# How can I write a command in a newly opened iTerm tab using AppleScript?

Tags: tabs, applescript, iterm2

I am a noob to Applescript and have searched a lot and found a lot of helpful information, but I can't seem to crack the final piece in getting this to work:

```
tell application "iTerm"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "t" using {command down}
    end tell
    write text "echo 'hello'" in selected tab
end tell
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After creating a new tab, the `current session` will set that the new tab and you can `write text` to it.

```
tell application "iTerm2"
  tell current window
    create tab with default profile
    tell current session
        write text "echo StackOverflow"
    end tell
  end tell
end tell
```